# Upload laravel to web hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I was confused when I want to upload all applications using the framework laravel. In the hosting I want to access directly :

> www.mydomain.com

(without /public)
Please help me

Answer (score 2):

As per the [installation instructions](http://laravel.com/docs/install#installation) you must point the Virtual Host to the public folder, for example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/JonSnow/Sites/MySite/public
    ServerName mysite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

If you're not using Virtual Hosts and are simply specifying the `DocumentRoot` you would do something like:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/public"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using shared hosting? Some hosts only give you access to the web root (never ideal).

If so a hacky workaround would be to use a .htaccess file to redirect web-root to web-root/public but this is not a good place to put a framework.

Untested but something like this should work:

```
# Send user to /public/
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC]
```

Comment: This answer could be improved with an example htaccess file and/or some links to find out more about how to do this.

Comment: +1 Because this does work; even though it's noted that it's not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option on shared hosting is to place everything outside of the 'public_html' folder, and then place the contents of 'public' into 'public_html'.
You will then just need to update `$paths['public'] = 'public';` to `$paths['public'] = 'public_html';` inside the paths.php file in the root.